# How to use event.target.result to get data when uploading multiple files from different input buttons - React

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-redux, redux-saga, react-hook-form

I will send my input data to the back-end using React-Redux-Saga. There are 3 input files in different input buttons in React Hook form.

```
const imageFile = formValues.inputImage[0]
const letterFile = formValues.inputLetter[0]
const cvFile = formValues.inputCV[0]
```

I have the function to send data to the back-end. But the problem is I do not know how to implement to get the data of file when using `event.target.result` while I have 3 files uploaded.

Here is how I implement to send data when there is 1 file uploaded from the input

```
export const createUploadFileChannel = (url, file, opt) => {
  return eventChannel((emitter) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    let reader = new FileReader()

    const onProgress = (e) => {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        const progress = e.loaded / e.total
        emitter({ progress })
      }
    }

    const onFailure = () => {
      emitter({ err: new Error('Upload failed') })
      emitter(END)
    }

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', onProgress)
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('error', onFailure)
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('abort', onFailure)

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      const { readyState, status } = xhr
      if (readyState === 4) {
        if (status === 200) {
          let resp = xhr.responseText
          console.log('-----------Inside Channel data:: ', resp)
          emitter({ success: true, data: resp })
          emitter(END)
        } else {
          onFailure(null)
        }
      }
    }

    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
      const body = {
        ...opt,
        AttachmentType: 2,
        Title: file.name,
        FileType: file.type,
        data: e.target.result
      }

      let nestedBody = nestPropertyAsObject(body, 'OpenWorkAttachments', [
        'AttachmentType',
        'Title',
        'FileType',
        'data'
      ])

      xhr.open('POST', url, true)
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application.json')
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        'Authorization',
        `Bearer ${store.getState().client.user.data[0].access_token}`
      )

      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(nestedBody))
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    return () => {
      xhr.upload.removeEventListener('progress', onProgress)
      xhr.upload.removeEventListener('error', onFailure)
      xhr.upload.removeEventListener('abort', onFailure)
      xhr.onreadystatechange = null
      xhr.abort()
    }
  }, buffers.sliding(2))
}
```

How I can take data of 3 files uploaded in different input?
Any help is very meaningful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple implement using the formData object

```js
   const formdata = new FormData();
    for(let i = 0 ; i<event.target.files.length; i++){
    formdata.append(event.target.files[i])
    // you can use the formdata object in your xhr 
   }
```

```html
<input type='file' multiple />
```

*Instead of xhr you can use axios. It is easy compared to xhr*

you can find implementation of it below since you are suing hooks.
https://www.bezkoder.com/react-hooks-multiple-file-upload/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I got the point after learn about that. But then I am curious about how I can implement that when my files are uploaded from different input button.